# Is there any why to put function inside function argument in r?

Tags: r, function, arguments

Lets say i have this function

```
 library(dplyr)
 x<-c(1,2,3,4,5)
 my_function <- function(){
  results <- x %>%
    sum()%>%
    sqrt()
 return(results)
 }

 my_function()
 [1] 3.872983
```

Is there any way in r to put the function i need to apply in the argument so my code will be something like that:

```
 my_function <- function(my_first_code,my_second_code){
 results <- x %>%
          my_first_code()%>%
          my_second_code()
 return(results)
 }
   my_function(max,sqrt)
   [1] 2.236068
```

Comment: you can pass it as promises to the function and then evaluate it by calling the name of the argument

Comment: Your second function works perfectly fine. Where is the question?

Comment: Wow! i didn't expect that the second function will work  thank you guys.

Answer (score 1):

Pass a function by using its name like this:

```
my_function <- function(x, fun1, fun2) {
  x %>%
    fun1 %>%
    fun2
}

my_function(1:5, sum, sqrt)
## [1] 3.872983
```

Usually it is done like this which allows the function to be passed or a character string naming it.

```
my_function <- function(x, fun1, fun2) {
  fun1 <- match.fun(fun1)
  fun2 <- match.fun(fun2)
  x %>%
    fun1 %>%
    fun2
}

my_function(1:5, sum, sqrt)
## [1] 3.872983
my_function(1:5, "sum", "sqrt")
## [1] 3.872983
```

Comment: I recognize this works as-is, have you run into problems recently (I know I have in the past) where the function parens (`()`) are required for the pipe to function?

Comment: Thank you that work, additional question what happen if x have NA  my_function(c(1:3,NA) ,sum(na.rm = T), sqrt) this code doesn't work.

Comment: You have to pass a function, not an expression.  Define `sum_na <- function(x) sum(x, na.rm = TRUE)` and then pass `sum_na`.